# Removing rects from movable space in a game

Tags: c++, animation, collision-detection

I've got a simple setup which has a ball bouncing around the screen, I want to be able to give the object rects which it cannot move inside (they will act as obstacles). Currently have the following logic to try accomplish this.

```
void AnimatableObject::ExcludeRects(AnimatableObject *obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < obj->numberOfExclusionBounds; i++) {
            SDL_Rect bounds = obj->exclusionBounds[i];

            /* TOUCHING SIDES OF THE RECT*/
            bool touchingTopOfRect = obj->m_dY + obj->m_dHeight > bounds.y &&
                obj->m_dY < bounds.y + bounds.h &&
                obj->m_dX > bounds.x &&
                obj->m_dX + obj->m_dWidth < bounds.x + bounds.w;

            bool touchingBottomOfRect = obj->m_dY < bounds.y + bounds.h &&
                obj->m_dY > bounds.y &&
                obj->m_dX > bounds.x &&
                obj->m_dX + obj->m_dWidth < bounds.x + bounds.w;

            bool touchingRightOfRect = obj->m_dX < bounds.x + bounds.w &&
                obj->m_dX > bounds.x &&
                obj->m_dY > bounds.y &&
                obj->m_dY + obj->m_dHeight < bounds.y + bounds.h;

            bool touchingLeftOfRect = obj->m_dX + obj->m_dWidth > bounds.x &&
                obj->m_dX + obj->m_dWidth < bounds.x + bounds.w &&
                obj->m_dY > bounds.y &&
                obj->m_dY + obj->m_dHeight > bounds.y + bounds.h;


            // Top of a rect.
            if (touchingTopOfRect) {
                obj->m_dY = bounds.y - obj->m_dHeight;
                obj->bottomContact = true;
            }

            // Bottom of Rect
            if (touchingBottomOfRect) {
                obj->m_dY = bounds.y + bounds.h;
                obj->topContact = true;
            }

            // Left Side of rect.
            if (touchingLeftOfRect) {
                obj->m_dX = bounds.x - obj->m_dWidth;
                obj->rightContact = true;
            }

            // Right Side of rect
            if (touchingRightOfRect) {
                printf("HIT RIGHT OF A OBSTACLE %d\n", bounds.w);

                obj->m_dX = bounds.x + bounds.w;
                obj->leftContact = true;
            }
        }
}
```

So this is called every frame and will loop through an array storing the rects which I want to be excluded from the object moveable area.

This is becoming very tricky to get working using this method, lots of times the conditionals are firing when they shouldn't. However my main issue is that this seems unnecessarily complicated to me. Is there a better way to be going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to greatly simply this using `SDL_HasIntersection`

Basic pseudocode would go along the lines of

```
for each collider rect
  if HasIntersection( bounds, colliderBounds )
    find the centre points of each rect (x+w/2, y+h/2)
    bool touchingLeft = ( bounds_centre.x < collider_centre.x )
    bool touchingRight = ( bounds_cenre.x > collider_centre.x )
    ... etc ...
```

see

http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HasIntersection

**edit**:  Another option would be to skip doing any collision detection yourself, and use the excellent Box2D instead:

http://box2d.org/